# How to put the Information get from Google Place API and store to Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, google-places-api

I'm follow the tutorial and implement the google place api to my file.
But I want to change it save to Firebase. Maybe save to a table "Location"

Anyone can guide me how to save it to firebase. The code I refer is from here:https://github.com/delaroy/AndroidLocationGeofencing
Thanks in advance and sorry for if there was lack of information Ii will added again.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zNY5.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbQtI.png)

```
package com.example.edward.neweventmanagementsystem;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.edward.neweventmanagementsystem.provider.PlaceContract;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

public class ManageLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener {

    // Constants
    public static final String TAG = ManageLocation.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 111;
    private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;

    // Member variables
    private PlaceListAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private boolean mIsEnabled;
    private GoogleApiClient mClient;
    private Geofencing mGeofencing;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    Context mContext;
    PlaceBuffer mPlaces;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is starting
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState The Bundle that contains the data supplied in onSaveInstanceState
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_location);

        // Set up the recycler view
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.places_list_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mAdapter = new PlaceListAdapter(this, null);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


//        Switch onOffSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.enable_switch);
//        mIsEnabled = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(getString(R.string.setting_enabled), false);
//        onOffSwitch.setChecked(mIsEnabled);
//        onOffSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
//                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
//                editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.setting_enabled), isChecked);
//                mIsEnabled = isChecked;
//                editor.commit();
//                if (isChecked) mGeofencing.registerAllGeofences();
//                else mGeofencing.unRegisterAllGeofences();
//            }
//
//        });


        mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();

        mGeofencing = new Geofencing(this, mClient);

    }

    /***
     * Called when the Google API Client is successfully connected
     *
     * @param connectionHint Bundle of data provided to clients by Google Play services
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle connectionHint) {
        refreshPlacesData();
        Log.i(TAG, "API Client Connection Successful!");
    }

    /***
     * Called when the Google API Client is suspended
     *
     * @param cause cause The reason for the disconnection. Defined by constants CAUSE_*.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "API Client Connection Suspended!");
    }

    /***
     * Called when the Google API Client failed to connect to Google Play Services
     *
     * @param result A ConnectionResult that can be used for resolving the error
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "API Client Connection Failed!");
    }

    public void refreshPlacesData() {
        Uri uri = PlaceContract.PlaceEntry.CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor data = getContentResolver().query(
                uri,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);

        if (data == null || data.getCount() == 0) return;
        List<String> guids = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            guids.add(data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(PlaceContract.PlaceEntry.COLUMN_PLACE_ID)));
        }
        PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mClient,
                guids.toArray(new String[guids.size()]));
        placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
                mAdapter.swapPlaces(places);
                mGeofencing.updateGeofencesList(places);
                if (mIsEnabled) mGeofencing.registerAllGeofences();
            }
        });
    }


    public void onAddPlaceButtonClicked(View view) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.need_location_permission_message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        try {

            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            Intent i = builder.build(this);
            startActivityForResult(i, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("GooglePlayServices Not Available [%s]", e.getMessage()));
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("GooglePlayServices Not Available [%s]", e.getMessage()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("PlacePicker Exception: %s", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }


    /***
     * Called when the Place Picker Activity returns back with a selected place (or after canceling)
     *
     * @param requestCode The request code passed when calling startActivityForResult
     * @param resultCode  The result code specified by the second activity
     * @param data        The Intent that carries the result data.
     */
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
            if (place == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "No place selected");
                return;
            }

            final String placeID = place.getId();

            // Insert a new place into DB
//            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
//            contentValues.put(PlaceContract.PlaceEntry.COLUMN_PLACE_ID, placeID);
//            getContentResolver().insert(PlaceContract.PlaceEntry.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

            //Place the data into Firebase



            // Get live data information
            refreshPlacesData();
        }
    }

    public void onRingerPermissionsClicked(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onLocationPermissionClicked(View view) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ManageLocation.this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
   mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
        if (place == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "No place selected");
            return;
        }

        final String placeID = place.getId();
        //Place the data into Firebase
        insertPlcaeIdinDb(placeID);



        // Get live data information
        refreshPlacesData();
    }
}  
  private void insertPlcaeIdinDb(String placeID) 
  {
      mDatabase.child("yourBranchNameinDb").setValue(placeID );
   }
```

To understand what is
`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()`
you can follow Firebase for android official documentation from [there](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)

Comment: Thanks. Now can insert into database but it always replace the old record if add new location. I have change some of it [Screenshot 2] but feel like need to store also the place name and address but not sure how to code it.
Another problem is, if follow the code in https://github.com/delaroy/AndroidLocationGeofencing and change to the above code, the recycle view not able to show out the list of location that have added.

Comment: if you get the idea of storing in database please check this answer as accepted and i try to help you the link i give it to you it has all tutorials regarding firebase

Comment: @EdwardLiew its a long task you should try to create branches first in firebase

Comment: you need something like this to store places

{
  "places": {
    "some name or Id": {
      "place_name": "Ada Lovelace",
      "place_address":  "ghopper",
    },
    "some name or Id": { ... },
    "some name or Id": { ... }
  }
}

Comment: also you should have to use the main branch "places" to rad or insert any new record

Comment: No it can save to database already by using the Place place...mDatabaseReference.child("Location").child(placeID).setValue(place);

Comment: But i don't know how to get the result back from firebase.

Comment: and show in the list (recycle view by using the PlaceListAdapter)

Comment: you have to read the documentation for reading operations,can you check the answer as accepted so it can help the community!Thanks

Comment: ya, in this case the answer you post can. But i have added  final String placeID = place.getId(); above the insertPlaceIdinDb(place, placeID); , and in the insertPlaceinDb mDatabaseReference.child("Location").child(placeID).setValue(place);
so it would retrieve and store all the information of the place instaed only the placeId